# Getting an error when trying to pivot a data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created a data frame that looks like this.

```
           ticker   Adj Close
Date                         
2019-04-30    MMM  186.198486
2019-05-01    MMM  182.818604
2019-05-02    MMM  181.521667
2019-05-03    MMM  181.983444
2019-05-06    MMM  179.841537
```

When I hit the third line, I get an error.

```
df = df.reset_index()
df = df.set_index('Date')
table = df.pivot(columns='ticker')
```

Error message:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'reset_index'
```

I could swear this worked fine a couple years ago.  I don't know what changed since the last time I ran this script.

Comment: The data frame `df` is a pandas data frame right, if yes, then it should work. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html

Comment: The dataframe you're showing already has the index set.  Start with the dataframe before setting the index and then `df.pivot(index='Date', column='ticker')`

Comment: I tried this:
df = df.pivot(index='Date', column='ticker')

I get this error:
TypeError: pivot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'column'

Comment: Yes, df is a Pandas df.